# React-hook-form build problem when upgrading nextjs to version 12

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form

When I upgrade **nextjs** to **version 12** and I run `yarn dev` it has a problem in react-hook-form library:

> SyntaxError: Named export 'set' not found. The requested module **react-hook-form** is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
> CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using ....

Can anyone help me fix this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As David Cingolani mentioned, this problem was fixed in **react-hook-form** after version 7.22.5.

To update the lib to the **latest** version run

> npm i react-hook-form@latest

or

> yarn add react-hook-form@latest

To update to the most recent version or use the suffix "@7.22.5" to update to the exact version.

> E.g: npm i react-hook-form@7.22.5

Answer (score 47):

import your `yupResolver` slightly differently.

as opposed to:

```
import {yupResolver} from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
```

do:

```
import {yupResolver} from '@hookform/resolvers/yup/dist/yup';
```

Comment: I am still getting this error by doing this way.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my issue with next.js + TS

Comment: do you know how to make it work with storybook as well? I assume the error there is related...

Answer (score 3):

with the version  7.22.5 of react hook form this error was fixed

Comment: Leave a comment on next action like updating library.